# Eclipse regularly resets settings

Tags: eclipse

Eclipse Juno regularly resets all of its settings (.metadata). It starts from a clear desktop as if it was recently installed. So I need to restore .metadata once a week or two.

Why does it happen? Is it a known Eclipse problem?

UPDATED

This happens every time when I switch off second display.

Comment: Are you using the same workspace all the time?

Answer (score 0):

Do not put .metadata itself under version control. Only put contents of the workspace (i.e. projects) under version control. By manipulating the .metadata directory during checkouts, you are essentially breaking the workspace yourself.

The metadata directory *cannot* be shared by design and this will lead to trouble. See [What of Eclipse project .metadata can I safely ignore in Git/Mercurial?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4278601/what-of-eclipse-project-metadata-can-i-safely-ignore-in-git-mercurial) or [Which Eclipse files belong under version control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337304/which-eclipse-files-belong-under-version-control) for some more pointers about that.

Comment: You wrote "need to restore .metadata". I was of the impression this relates to version control. Do you mean you restore a file backup?